# Rear wiper arm Dodge

Tags: dodge, windshield-wipers, rear, caliber

I want to replace the rear wiper arm on my 2011 Dodge Caliber with the newer covered style.  The arm length is approx. 9 to 10 inches long.  The shaft is 6 mm.    How can I find an arm that will work?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!